# How to get the list of symbol and their types from a C code and its head file?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

for example. If I have a .c file and .h file like

example.c:

```
#include "example.h"
Uint32 a=0;
TestExample b=0;
```

example.h:

```
typedef Uint32 unsinged int;
#define TestExample int
```

And I want to get the information like:

```
[
{symbol:A, type:unsigned int},
{symbol:B, type: int}
]
```

Is there any solution exisited already in GCC?
I mean, for sure we could implement some kind of compilation phase to analysis the code. But I don't want to re create a brandly new solution. Maybe there are some tools I can start with.
Any better idea?

Comment: i bet llvm has a tool that can help

Comment: There are several static code analysis tools. What is your objective? By getting these symbols what you intend to accomplish?

Comment: Do you want to list all global/static variables?

Comment: The intention is that, base on the information, we can implement some validation on naming rules check， create stub functions etc.

Comment: @ssbssa  yes, not only the symbol, but also the type etc.

Comment: You want a symbol table

Comment: Not exactly what you want, but gdb can show you all global variables and their type with `info var -n`.